When does Ripley first get to see the adult xenomorph in Alien?
In Alien, the killing of Parker and Lambert is scary as hell, not least because Ripley can hear what's going on, but is powerless to help. But has she actually seen the adult xenomorph at this point? I think not.

I don't believe there is any evidence that she saw the adult xenomorph until after she's in the shuttle, near the end of the film. I believe that it shares a scene or two with her prior to that, hidden in the ductwork, but she does not see it.

INT. NARCISSUS
Ripley watching the final destiny of her ship and crew mates.
A very long moment.
Then, behind her, the lethal hand emerges from deep shadow.
The Alien has been in the shuttle-craft all along.
The cat yowls.
Ripley whirls.
Finding herself facing the Creature.


She does seem to see it earlier. I've answered below.

She has not seen the adult xenomorph prior to the deaths of Lambert and Parker. However, she does catch a glimpse of it before her encounter in the shuttle.
On the way to making her escape, Ripley discovers that the alien stands between her and the shuttle, blocking her from exiting the Nostromo. She peeks around a corner and just barely sees the xenomorph standing in a corridor. At this point, she leaves Jonesy and attempts to cancel the self destruct sequence. When that fails, she makes her way back to the shuttle and finds Jonesy unharmed and the xenomorph nowhere to be seen. She next sees it once she is on the shuttle after the Nostromo has exploded.
She sees the xenomorph 29 seconds into this clip of the scene.

Ah, thank you. I thought that night have been the case, but I only had the script, which describes her only as hearing it ahead of her.
